# ¿Es posible o tiene sentido crear una variable broadcast con un dataset en Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Tengo un Dataset de la forma:

```scala
val miDataSet: Dataset[MyDataCase] = dataset grande
```

Y tengo un job que lo usa varias veces de la forma:

```scala
class Processor(
  miDataSet: Dataset[MyDataCase]) {
  def metric1: Metric = {
    val metric: Metric = miDataSet.etc.etc.count()
    metric
  }
  def metric2: Metric = {
    val metric: Metric = miDataSet.etc2.etc2.count()
    metric
  }
  def metric3: Metric = {
    val metric: Metric = miDataSet.etc3.etc3.count()
    metric
  }
  ...
}
```

Sé que cuando mandas en broadcast una variable, este resultado se copia en los ejecutores del cluster y lo que me gustaría sería hacer algo como:

```scala
class Processor(
  miDataSet: Broadcast[Dataset[MyDataCase]]) {
  def metric1: Metric = {
    val metric: Metric = miDataSet.value.etc.etc.count()
    metric
  }
...
}
```

De esta manera imagino que no consultaría todo el tiempo el dataset en el driver y mejor consultaría su copia local.

Lo he intentado en varios ejemplos y parece que funciona. Sin embargo, en los ejemplo he visto que el broadcasting se utiliza con valores como arrays, maps, sequences, pero no datasets.

Sabrá alguien si crear un Broadcast de un dataset tiene sentido o si hay algunas consideraciones a demás del tamaño?

Answer (score 3):

En el *broadcast* lo que hay que considerar es el trabajo de serializar/deserializar los datos cuando se envían a cada worker, da igual que sea un array o el objeto que sea. Los arrays, maps o secuencias son más compactos a la hora de seriealizarlos, importante cuando son grandes cantidades de datos los que necesitas compartir.

En el caso de los datasets, no se usan los serializadores estándar. Se usan **encoders* que entienden la estructura interna de los datasets y son capaces de transformar eficientemente estos datasets en datos binarios usables internamente. Si te funciona, yo no me preocuparía demasiado

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Si sabía eso pero no estaba seguro si es lo mismo mandar un Dataset que no mandarlo, o que mandar un objeto de scala/java. Al final me di cuenta que no había cambio en el performance así que removí esa característica del broadcast por simplicidad.